# Hide installed software from Windows search result

Tags: windows-10

I have recently installed a game in my PC which I love to play, but at the same time, my cousin who is here to stay, too started playing it and doesn't want to get away from my PC. I have hidden the shortcut, but my cousin just goes to the search bar in Windows and type the name of the game and she gets it right there. I would've uninstalled the game, but I don't want to since I too love to play.

**So, I am wondering if there is some way so that I can hide the game from the search results of the computer?** I have tried changing the attribute of Google Chrome shortcut to hidden in 'general' tab but it still isn't going away from the search results.

Comment: You probably should not share the same Windows Profile for any variety of reasons. Reinstall the game only as your user (not All Users), and log off when you are not using the computer

Comment: Is there no way around? like tweaking registry etc. ?

Comment: If an application is installed for the user in use, then it can be found.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hide legitimately installed programs from being found in the user name they were installed under.

So the only other practical approach is for you and the other user to have separate and different user names.

Then uninstall the game and install it for your user name only (not All Users).

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to avoid uninstalling and reinstalling but seems like that's impossible now.